# Dotenv variables loading but db connection error when variable used

Tags: node.js, dotenv

Testing to see if dotenv is working and I have the following:

.env

```
DB_PORT = 8000;
```

server.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

....

const PORT = process.env.DB_PORT || 8001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

If I run this I get the error (although it shows the varible is loading):

> Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 8000;

Change the port and the same thing:

> Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 3000;

If I comment out DB_PORT in the .evn file it works on 8001. If I leave it commented out and enter the following in the VS Code terminal:

```
export DB_PORT = 3600;
```

it runs on 3600.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `EACCESS` means that port (8000) is already taken. You can either kill what's on `8000` or choose a different port. Though, given your env variable, are you trying to start a server on the same port as your DB?

Comment: Sadly not - happens on any port I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the semicolon in your `.env`. You don't terminate lines in a `.env` file with a semicolon, just a standard line break.

Comment: Amazing - such a simple fix. Thanks.